# Prove that: $2^{n+1}|k^{2^n}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let's denote that $k$ is an odd number and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that:

> $$2^{n+1}|k^{2^n}-1$$

Could you give me any HINT how to start with this?

Comment: **Hint:** $k^{2^n}-1=(k^{2^{n-1}}-1)(k^{2^{n-1}}+1).$ Apply this again, and again, and again... Additionally, note that if $k$ is odd, $k^{2^m}+1$ is $\cdots ?$

Comment: $k = 2m -1$. When we unfold $k^{2^n}-1$ we receive $k^{2^n}-1 = (k^{2^{n-1}}+1)(k^{2^{n-2}}+1) \ldots (k^{2^2}+1) (k^{2^1}+1)(k^{2^0}-1)$. Last factor equals to $(2m-1-1)=2(m-1)$. Well, can get from every factor one $2$. So, I have received only $2^n$. Where is a mistake?

Comment: You have made a slight mistake. The tail of that expression should be $(k^2+1)(k+1)(k-1)$, not just $(k^2+1)(k-1)$. So it is indeed divisible by $2^{n+1}$. In fact, since one of $k-1,\, k+1$ is a multiple of $4$ it is divisible by $2^{n+2}$.

Comment: That's true. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @L.F.: So, that gives an induction kind of proof. Very nice.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591176/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$k=(2m-1) \implies k^{2^n}=(2m-1)^{2^n} \implies 2m^{2^n}$-$2^n \choose 2$ $2m^{2^n-1} + \dots$-$2^n \choose 2^n-1$$2^{1}+ 1$

$k^{2^n}-1=2m^{2^n}$-$2^n \choose 2$ $2m^{2^n-1} + \dots$-$2^n \choose 2^n-1$$2^{1}$

Do you see that every term is a multiple of $2^{n+1}$?, last term being $2^{n+1} \cdot m$.

Comment: +1, Yes, thanks a lot for your answer. It helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that!