# Showing the existence of an integral number

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, integers, prime-factorization

Recently, in high-school competition maths, I came across such a question:

Does there exist an integer $n$, with $2000$ factors, such that $n$ divides $2^n+1$, or:

$$n\mid{2^n+1}?$$
This question is tagged as a practice question for number theory and is part of a lecture on indefinite equations. The solution was not provided, and I could not seem to figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note: The case of distinct factors is IMO 2000 shortlist, Number Theory qn 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful lemma is that for all $k$ we have $$3^k\,|\,2^{3^k}+1$$

The proof is a straight forward induction, and may be found, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591176/3n1-divides-23n1).  Indeed, one can show a slightly stronger result than we require.

These are not all the $n$ such that $n\,|\,2^n+1$ but they suffice to answer this question, since $3^k$ has $k+1$ divisors.

Worth remarking:  the $n$ for which $n\,|\,2^n+1$ which are not powers of $3$ form a rather erratic list.  in OEIS they form sequence [A016057](http://oeis.org/A016057).

Comment: $3^k$ has $k+1$ divisors, not *prime* divisors right?

Comment: @pooja  Yes.  Clearly $3^k$ has only one prime divisor.

Comment: Ah ok you're right! I was looking at another sol'n where it asked for $n$ to have $2000$ distinct prime factors haha

Comment: [this](https://web.evanchen.cc/static/otis-samples/soln-DNY-ntconstruct.pdf) variation of the problem looks hard. 3rd page last line

Comment: @pooja  Yeah, that's clearly a lot harder.

Comment: How do you know theorems like this

Comment: @AaronyJamesys  Lots of experience playing with factoring problems and such. In this particular case, numerical examples should tell you that powers of $3$ come up a lot...that should lead you to this result.

Comment: @lulu so if you didn't know the theorem, would you just have to test every number?

Comment: Well...numerical examples are a huge part of number theory.  I'd always start by trying to list a bunch of examples.  See if I can spot a pattern.  Here, for instance, one should quickly see, empirically,  that all "good" $n$ are divisible by $3$.  Try to prove that!  What about divisibility by $9$?